# grep with two or more words, one line by file with many files

Tags: linux, grep

everyone. I have

`file 1.log:
text1 value11 text
text text
text2 value12 text`

`file 2.log:
text1 value21 text
text text
text2 value22 text`

I want:

`value11;value12
value21;value22`

For now I grep values in separated files and paste later in another file, but I think this is not a very elegant solution because I need to read all files more than one time, so I try to use grep for extract all data in a single cat | grep line, but is not the result I expected.

I use:
`cat *.log | grep -oP "(?<=text1 ).*?(?= )|(?<=text2 ).*?(?= )" | tr '\n' '; '`

or

`cat *.log | grep -oP "(?<=text1 ).*?(?= )|(?<=text2 ).*?(?= )" | xargs`

but I get in each case:

`value11;value12;value21;value22`

`value11 value12 value21 value22`

Thank you so much.

Comment: wrt `I want:` - there are so many ways you might get that output. Strings starting with `value`, strings that don't start with `text`, middle field from 3-field lines, 2nd field from 1st and 3rd line of each file, strings before `text`, strings after `text1` or `text2`, etc., etc. [edit] your question to explain **why** that should be the output.

Comment: Hi. I can extract values (11, 12, 21, 22) with regex in the grep options. I need this values in one single line for file. grep without extra pipelines outputs al values in a single list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '$0=="text1" || $0=="text2"{getline; printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=";"} ENDFILE{if(sep)print""; sep=""}' *.log
value11;value12
value21;value22
```

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '
    $0=="text1" || $0=="text2" {
        getline
        printf "%s%s",sep,$0
        sep=";"
     }
     ENDFILE {
        if(sep)print""
        sep=""
     }' *.log
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]+'`

  This tells awk to treat any sequence of whitespace (newlines, blanks, tabs, etc) as a record separator.
- `$0=="text1" || $0=="text2"{getline; printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=";"}`

  This tells awk to look file records that matches either `text1 or`text2`.  For those records and those records only the commands in curly braces are executed.  Those commands are:

  - `getline` tells awk to read in the next record.
  - `printf "%s%s",sep,$0` tells awk to print the variable `sep` followed by the word in the record.
  - After we print the first match, the command `sep=";"` is executed which tells awk to set the value of `sep` to a semicolon.

    As we start each file, `sep` is empty.  This means that the first match from any file is printed with no separator preceding it.  All subsequent matches from the same file will have a `;` to separate them.
- `ENDFILE{if(sep)print""; sep=""}`

  After the end of each file is reached, we print a newline if `sep` is not empty and then we set `sep` back to an empty string.

#### Alternative: Printing the second word if the first word ends with a number

In an alternative interpretation of the question (hat tip: [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin)), we want to print the second word on any line for which the first word ends with a number.  In that case, try:

```
$ awk '$1~/[0-9]$/{printf "%s%s",sep,$2; sep=";"} ENDFILE{if(sep)print""; sep=""}' *.log
value11;value12
value21;value22
```

In the above, `$1~/[0-9]$/` selects the lines for which the first word ends with a number and `printf "%s%s",sep,$2` prints the second field on that line.

#### Discussion

The original command was:

```
$ cat *.log | grep -oP "(?<=text1 ).*?(?= )|(?<=text2 ).*?(?= )" | tr '\n' '; '
value11;value12;value21;value22;
```

Note that, when using most unix commands, `cat` is rarely ever needed.  In this case, for example, `grep` accepts a list of files.  So, we could easily do without the extra `cat` process and get the same output:

```
$ grep -hoP "(?<=text1 ).*?(?= )|(?<=text2 ).*?(?= )" *.log | tr '\n' '; '
value11;value12;value21;value22;
```

Comment: I like the solution. What about looking at `$2` with a regex of `^.*[0-9][0-9][0-9]*$` (or similar) to remove the hard requirement of `text1` and `text2`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your interpretation of the question differs from mine.  You might be right.  Inspired by your comment, I added a solution that looks for lines for which `$1` ends with a number.  (The OP's original regex looks for the word after text1 or text2 but does not anchor text1 or text2 to the beginning of the line.  That is, however, the only place his examples show them.   I think he has to clarify.)

Comment: You should mention the awk scripts are gawk-only for multi-char RS and ENDFILE and point oit that that use of getline isn't safe (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024) and how you approach this problem will really depend on what the actual text is you are looking for. If for instance your lines of concern start with `text{1,2,...}` and then what you want in the second field can be anything, then his approach is optimal. However, if the values in the first field and vary and what you are really interested in is records where you have `valueXX` in the second field, then an approach keying off the second field may be what you are looking for.

Taking for example your second field, if the text you are interested in is in the form `valueXX` (where `XX` are two or more digits at the end of the field), you can process only those records where your second field matches and then use a simple conditional testing whether `FNR == 1` to control the `';'` delimiter output and `ENDFILE` to control the new line similar to:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^value[0-9][0-9][0-9]*$/ {
    printf "%s%s", (FNR == 1) ? "" : ";", $2
}
ENDFILE {
    print ""
}' file1.log file2.log
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^value[0-9][0-9][0-9]*$/ {
    printf "%s%s", (FNR == 1) ? "" : ";", $2
}
ENDFILE {
    print ""
}' file1.log file2.log
value11;value12
value21;value22
```

Look things over and consider your actual input files and then either one of these two approaches should get you there.

Comment: Nice use of awk! You should mention that `ENDFILE` is gawk-only though.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Yes, if not using `gawk`, you would need to handle the change with an additional variable saving, e.g. `last = FNR` and then check if `FNR < last` to catch the file change otherwise.

Comment: ... and do it in the `END` section too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want the `values` but search for the `text[12]` ie. to get the word after matching search word, not the matching search word:

```
$ awk -v s="^text[12]$" '                   # set the search regex *
FNR==1 {                                    # in the beginning of each file
    b=b (b==""?"":"\n")                     # terminate current buffer with a newline
}
{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++)                       # iterate all but last word
        if($i~s)                            # if current word matches search pattern
            b=b (b~/^$|\n$/?"":";") $(i+1)  # add following word to buffer
}
END {                                       # after searching all files
    print b                                 # output buffer
}' *.log
```

Output:

```
value11;value12
value21;value22
```

`*` regex could be for example `^(text1|text2)$`, too.